# Url Encoding method for Special Character  in c#

Tags: c#, http, urlencode, vbulletin

I use post method to submit data to and i have used

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string data)
```

for Url Encode of data. But for some certain string the data at server side is shown different then what i submitted.

EX:

```
string data = "¦=¦=¦";
data = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data);
```

after submitting data to server it shows string as **Â¦=Â¦=Â¦** but original string was **¦=¦=¦**.

And which url encode i should use that can encode "**(**" to **%28** , "**)**" to **%29**. I can find this.

I also used HttpUtility.UrlEncodeUnicode ,HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode but don't work.
Which url encoding is suitable for this type of string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code example you are using ASCII for char "¦" this is not a valid ASCII char.
Use Unicode and it might work.

```
System.Text.UnicodeEncoding uni = new UnicodeEncoding();
byteArray = uni.GetBytes(data);
```

Comment: You are using ASCII for char "¦" this is not a valid ASCII char. Use Unicode and it might work.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using again, as when I test this I get the ¦=¦=¦ as expected. However I am using MVC controller.

Comment: My code is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158916/what-url-encoding-web-browser-uses

Answer (score 2):

Use HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data) to get it back as "¦=¦=¦"

Comment: I would suggest you keep the encoding same on each side 
e.g             string data = "¦=¦=¦";
            data = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(data, Encoding.UTF8);
            string dataOnServerSide = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(data, Encoding.UTF8);

Comment: you can achieve decode from server side by Creating Custom HttpHandler http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx

Comment: didn't work for me. I can find the problem is with my code or else?

Comment: i think i have problem in sending of that data stream but not sure.

Comment: Incase you haven't, Install Fiddler2 and use it to trace request and data, check the raw format, it will give you better idea whats going on

Comment: i have installed fiddler2 and raw data are missed match with raw data using the browser so i think this may be sending code fault. So i have added the sending code that i am using now.